# Can it be assigned a different icon to each of the Whisker-menu "Search Actions"?

Tags: xfce, icons, launcher, whisker-menu

Whisker Menu launcher has a great feature called "Search Actions" that can show and run any command as if it were a launcher (without the need to create such a launcher). Any file or folder can be found and opened with a key or a sequence of letters if set as "pattern".

[image]

But all such searches are displayed with the generic same icon (depending on the icon set).

[image]

Even the default pattern  `!` for "run in terminal" shows the same folder with the search symbol, instead of a terminal icon or one more to the point, which is confusing.

[image]

Is there a way to edit the icon shown by Whisker-Menu application launcher for each specific "search action" so that it gets more specific/related to the search? (For example, have a text-like icon when opening a text file — or the icon of the text editor etc, a terminal icon for "run in terminal", a web-related icon for "Web search" — default pattern:`?` — etc.)

---

Maybe I can get closer to an answer if I first have one for this other question:

**[Where are the “Search actions” of Whisker Menu saved?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/636015/341192)**

Comment: I have to admit that I do not understand what you meant by "have a text-like icon when opening a text file".

Comment: @X.LINK - I'll add an image if that is obscure. I mean when I open a text file in LO Writer in this way  (with the "Search Action" feature of Whisker Menu) I want to see a "text" icon or the Writer icon, **instead of a generic "folder-search" icon for all "search actions"**. I guess that (given the title "search actions") this feature was meant for searching files and folders, but it is even by default oriented to a larger scope (and thus  its name is odd). For example `!` is the default pattern for "run in terminal", but it shows the same folder with the search symbol, which is confusing.

Comment: Okay that's better, what you meant is that the Search Action's results should have its icons fectched from the command it launched (in your case, LibreOffice or a notepad). Oddly, the question's title was more accurate than the description.